# $p^p+q^q $ is a multiple of $p+q $ when $q=p+2$.

Tags: number-theory

For $p=1$ and $q=3$

$1^1+3^3=28=7\times (1+3) $

for $p=2$ and $q=4$ it is not true.

for $p=3$ and $q=5$,
$3^3+5^5=27+3125=3152=394\times (3+5) $

By computer, it seems that it is true for $p \;\;\text {odd} \; \ge 5$.
Can we confirm this result by an other approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just say $\frac{p^p+(p+2)^{p+2}}{2p+2}$ is an integer for $p>2$

Comment: Doesn't appear to be true for $p=8,16$ either.  (I just looked at powers of $2$).

Comment: @JacobClaassen You used too much characters to say the same thing.

Comment: Also fails for both $32$ and $34$.  So far, $34$ is the least counterexample I have that isn't a power of $2$, though I have not searched systematically.

Comment: $p=14,24$ are also counterexamples. I'll stop searching now.

Comment: If $7\not | \;n$  then $n^6\equiv 1 \pmod 7.$  So $6^6+8^8\equiv $ $1+8^28^6\equiv $ $1+8^2\not \equiv$ $ 0 \pmod 7.$ So $14\not | \;6^6+8^8.$

Comment: Does your computer have a fever?  Any power of $6$ is congruent to $6$ mod $10.$.... So $4^4+6^6\equiv$ $ 16^2+6^6\equiv$ $ 6^2+6^6\equiv$ $ 6+6 \pmod {10}$, so $10 \not |\;4^4+6^6.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet good morning. It seems that the user was wrong, and this  question clarified because there were counterexamples and now an answer. Then, from my viewpoint, if one wants to provide an advice to this user (that answered a huge number of questions in this site MSE, as you) could be that check the algorithm of such  computer program (... I when I was wrong in myself questions, I deleted such questions in first minutes after I asked the posts). Best wishes.

Comment: @user243301 I cannot delete from mobile.

Comment: I believe that when there are answers of a question, in these sites Stack Exchange, one can not delete freely the post (one can delete posts but the site send you a warning).  I am saying that in my posts, if   in the first minutes I consider that the question is not the best, then early before there is an answer (of an user that also want help me with a contribution), I say thanks and I delete my question. Notice that thus I am not saying that you should delete this question, was just an opinion and my strategy, maybe even wrong. Best wishes.

Comment: @user243301 I said Thanks in advance. i edited it and now it is a good question. Thanks again.

Comment: @user243301. My remark about the computer flu was in jest. I feel sure the O.P. knows that the computer's error is (almost certainly) a software bug.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I am agree with your words, best wishes.

Answer (score 4):

If $q = p + 2$, $p + q = 2p + 2$.  For convenience, let $n = p + 1$.
So $p^p + q^q = (n-1)^{n-1} + (n+1)^{n+1}$, and you're asking whether this is
divisible by $2n$.  That turns out to be true if $n$ is even, but not if $n$ is odd.  Instead, $ p^p + q^q - 2 = (n-1)^{n-1} + (n+1)^{n+1} - 2 $ is divisible by $2n =p+q$ if $n$ is odd.